# Script not working anymore, .group() used to work but now is throwing an error

Tags: python

This is the portion of the code that's causing trouble:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df
df.columns = ['Campaigns', 'Impressions', 'Attempts', 'Spend']
Campaigns = df['Campaigns']
IDs = []
for c in Campaigns:
    num = re.search(r'\d{6}',c).group()
    IDs.append(num)
pieces = [df,pd.DataFrame(IDs)]
frame = pd.concat(pieces, axis=1, join='outer',ignore_index=False)
frame['ID'] = frame[0]
del frame[0]
frame
```

This is the error:

```
Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

When I try things individually in ipython everything works, for example:

```
in>> test = 'YP_WON2_SP8_115436'
in>> num = re.search(r'\d{6}',test)
in>> num.group()
out>> '115436'
```

I've tried splitting up the code as above and it still throws the same error.

Comment: can you add a `print c` as you iterate through and reppost with the output? Likely, one or more of whatever is returned for campaigns does not match the regex

Comment: Can you print df['Campaigns']?

Comment: Ah there is one in there doesn't match the regex, will ad error handling - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the code:

```
df
df.columns = ['Campaigns', 'Impressions', 'Attempts', 'Spend']
Campaigns = df['Campaigns']
ID = []
for c in Campaigns:
    m = re.search(r'\d{6}',c)
    if m:
        num = re.search(r'\d{6}',c).group()
        ID.append(num)
    else:
        ID.append('No ID')
pieces = [df,pd.DataFrame(ID)]
frame = pd.concat(pieces, axis=1, join='outer',ignore_index=False)
frame['ID'] = frame[0]
del frame[0]
frame
```